# Rails 4: How do I find an array of user_ids in a different table excluding current_user id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Session's table that stores user_ids and their session. I need to find all users, in a Session's table, currently logged in, are followed by a user, as in a Twitter followed, but exclude current_user id from the list. Here is my current code:

```
Session.where.not(:user_id => current_user).pluck(current_user.following.map(&:user_id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an array of the ids in question, try:

```
logged_in_user_ids = Session.where(user_id: current_user.following.map(&:id)).where.not(user_id: current_user).pluck(:user_id)
```

For the users themselves you might then do:

```
User.where(id: logged_in_user_ids)
```

Comment: Thanks @riarcombe. I am getting `undefined method user_id`. Just as I have before, and it's on `Session.where(user_id: current_user.following.map(&:user_id)).where.not(user_id: current_user).pluck(:user_id)`

Comment: OK. I edited by answer. My guess is the current_user.following gives you a collection of users... need to map the id in this case.

Comment: Awesome, that's it! Thanks @rlarcombe! I'll set the credit to you shortly.